# Stuck using unity LoadImage

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d

I get an image from internal memory and load image using LoadImage but this LoadImage function feels heavy and causes my runtime to be stuck for 1 second.

```
 public Texture2D GetTexture() {
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    var texture = new Texture2D(2,2, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
    texture.LoadImage(bytes);
    return texture; 
 }
```

What's the best way to load an image and not be stuck when using it?

Comment: I think you mean `stuck` (as in freeze) not `stack` (as in pile of things on top of each other)

Comment: Unfortunately both FileIO and txture loading are slow. The first one you could avoid a bit by using asynchronous FileIO. The second unfortunately can only be done on the Unity main thread

Comment: @derHugo ahh sorry typo but thanks... 
hmm,, is this a weakness of unity? I have visited many links but the answer is the same as yours..

Comment: You can load the texture into Texture2D before the texture is needed and then just use prepared texture. This will increase used memory, but there will be no delay in loading the texture.

Comment: @stazik hmm its good idea for other issue but not for this. I use gyromotion technology.. so whenever this LoadImage is used it will look freeze